# replacing string with a period isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to obfuscate an email address on a web page. I have a regex that converts the @ to *xy* and the period to *yy*. That's working. I have a js that executes when the page is submitted to convert them back but that is not working. That script is:

```
function undo(){
    var oldfield = document.getElementById('hchtest').value;
    var newfield = oldfield.replace("_xy_", "@");
    var nu2field = newfield.replace("_yy_", "\.");

    document.getElementById('hchtst2').value = nu2field;
}
```

The statement that is not working is var nu2field = newfield.replace(*yy*, ".");

I have tried every combination I can think of (e.g. without the escape character, as a regular expression, etc.) but no joy.

I would also like to know it if it is possible to make this elegant by eliminating the multi-step replace.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape `.` inside a string. `.replace(/_yy_/g,'.')` should work fine.

Also, you can chain replaces:

```
document.getElementById('hchtst2').value =
    document.getElementById('hchtest').value.replace(/_xy_/g,'@').replace(/_yy_/g,'.');
```

But what happens if the original string contains `_xy_` or `_yy_`?

Comment: +1 for "But what happens if the original string contains _xy_ or _yy_". The OP should consider this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want this instead? Why the extra underbars?

```
var newfield = oldfield.replace("xy", "@");
var nu2field = newfield.replace("yy", "\.");
```

In any case, here's another solution:

```
var newfield = oldfield.split("xy").join("@");
var nu2field = newfield.replace("yy").join(".");
```

And a one-liner:

```
var newfield = oldfield.split("xy").join("@").split("yy").join(".");
```

Comment: Gentlemen, I really appreciate the responses. It worked perfectly. My experience with javascript is limited and I really appreciate the elegance of the responses. PS: I was using the underscores while I was debugging. The string will be different in the live code. Thanks again.